# Entity Framework producing two extra columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.X and a code-first approach.

My requirement is I have tables

1. User
2. Product

While entering product I need Creator Name, Modifier Name to keep track and these two should reference User table. Because those who entered/modified should be in a user table.

My model is:

```
public class User : AuditableEntity
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(35)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public long MobileNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string EmailId { get; set; }

    public string MiscData { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products1 { get; set; }
}

public class Product : AuditableEntity
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "Money")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(35)]
    public override string CreatedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CreatedBy;
        }
        set
        {
            base.CreatedBy = value;
        }
    }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(35)]
    public override string ModifiedBy
    {
        get
        {
            return base.ModifiedBy;
        }
        set
        {
            base.ModifiedBy = value;
        }
    }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
    public User User1 { get; set; }
}
```

But when executing this it generates Db without error and it creates foreign column on `CreatedBy`, `ModifiedBy` columns in `Product`. However in the products it creates `User_UserId`, `User_UserId1` as extra columns.

I am new to Entity Framework.

Please help me.

**UPDATE**

> When i changed the referencing to one column say only CreatedBy that extra column is not coming in products. But when i reference one more column as shown above the problem is coming.

Comment: Try adding `[InverseProperty("UserId ")]`. See this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483019/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-annotate-a-foreign-key-for-a-default-valu

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze Thanks for reply.  where i need to add this property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This didn't solve the problem and is left only for historical information. Please see the UPDATE for the solution.**

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483019/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-annotate-a-foreign-key-for-a-default-valu). Try adding `[InverseProperty("UserId ")]` like this:

```
[InverseProperty("UserId ")]
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
public User User { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("UserId ")]
[ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
public User User1 { get; set; }
```

**UDPATE**

Also, EF might be confused where to map your `User.Products` and `User.Products1`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121460/entity-framework-code-first-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-to-same) and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships) on code-first relationships. Try changing it to:

```
[InverseProperty("User")]
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

[InverseProperty("User1")]
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried like u said its giving me this error 

**the property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter**

Comment: Thanks man really u saved my time. I was not able to get it since i am very new.